java.io.InterruptedIOException on outbound requests using ohkttp and hystrix
while making outbound requests to an external api the request is getting interrupted at exactly 2 seconds
we have multiple other integrations using the same dependancy of ohttp3 and hystrix and is not seeing the issue
                        at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream.waitForIo$okhttp(Http2Stream.kt:660)
                        at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream.takeHeaders(Http2Stream.kt:140)
                        at `enter code here`okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2ExchangeCodec.readResponseHeaders(Http2ExchangeCodec.kt:97)
                        at okhttp3.internal.connection.Exchange.readResponseHeaders(Exchange.kt:110)
                        at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.kt:93)
                        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
                        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:34)
                        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
                        at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:95)
                        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
                        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83)
                        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
                        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76)
                        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
                        at datadog.trace.instrumentation.okhttp3.TracingInterceptor.intercept(TracingInterceptor.java:39)
                        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
                        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:201)
                        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.execute(RealCall.kt:154)
                        at in.test.external.hystrix.command.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:79)
                        at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:302)
                        at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:298)
                        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:46)
                        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35)
                        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
                        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
                        at datadog.trace.instrumentation.rxjava.TracedOnSubscribe.call(TracedOnSubscribe.java:47)
                        at datadog.trace.instrumentation.rxjava.TracedOnSubscribe.call(TracedOnSubscribe.java:14)
                        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
                        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
                        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
                        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
                        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151)
                        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51)
                        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35)
                        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151)
                        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41)
                        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30)
                        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
                        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
                        at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10151)
                        at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:94)
                        at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContexSchedulerAction$1.call(HystrixContexSchedulerAction.java:56)
                        at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContexSchedulerAction$1.call(HystrixContexSchedulerAction.java:47)
                        at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContexSchedulerAction.call(HystrixContexSchedulerAction.java:69)
                        at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
                        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
                        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
                        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
                        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
                        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)```

